# How can you solve this integral of an unknown function?

Tags: calculus, physics

I came to this equation while trying to get the time a ball takes in a given surface under the influence of gravity. (Monotonically decreasing height is used to keep it simple)

$$\int_{h_i}^0  \sqrt   \frac {h-h_i} {{1+f'(h)^2}} dh $$ 
Note that $(f(h),h)$  would be the path the particle follows, always staying in contact with the surface.

Is it possible to solve this generally,  for unknown f?

Comment: There's no equation here, only an expression, so there's nothing to solve...

Comment: For general $f$, probably no simplifications. That's okay though, this is a fair final expression, solvable for some $f$.

Comment: I was trying to "prove" that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautochrone_curve) is unique and find that $f$